# Redis: How do you iterate through all hashes and build a list of values for a given field?

Tags: redis

Say I have a bunch of hashes, and all of those hashes have a "nickname" field.

I want to build a list of all nicknames, so I want to iterate through every hash in my redis database, collecting all values where the hash has a "nickname" field.

Is this something that can be accomplished in redis?

It seems like this isn't possible with just the commands redis provides alone, that I'd have to use another language like JavaScript (the language my app uses) to accomplish this.

Is this correct?

Comment: You can use `HSCAN` command to iterate all hashes in the database.

Comment: @for_stack nope, you can use `SCAN` to scan all keys, do a `TYPE` on each and if it is a Hash, and only then, use `HSCAN`.

Comment: @for_stack also, you don't need the final `HSCAN`, you can replace it with `HGET` ;)

Comment: @ItamarHaber My mistake. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

This is do-able in Redis but requires either [maintaining your own indices](https://redis.io/topics/indexes) or using [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch) to do the heavy lifting.